# How do I rewrite this expression so that it can be used with the binomial theorem?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I've been stuck on this problem on my homework for a while. I have a expression

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}5^{3n+k}(-6)^{2k-2}$$

which I need to re-write in the form of

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k$$

so that I can use the binomial theorem and turn it into closed form.

I'm able to figure out the $(-6)^{2k-2} = ((-6)^2)^{k-1} = 36^{k-1} = \frac{36^k}{36}$ part of the expression, but I can't figure out how to rewrite $5^{3n+k}$ as $x^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $5^{3n+k}=5^{3n}5^k = (5^3)^n(5^{-1})^{-k}$... Do you see how to continue?

> Hint 2: $(5^3)^n(5^{-1})^{-k} = 125^n5^n(5^{-1})^n(5^{-1})^{-k}$...

Comment: No--I don't see how I can go from $25^n \frac{1}{5}^k$ to $x^n \frac{1}{x}^k$ because I can't have $x=5$ and $x=25$ at the same time.

Comment: See my added hint.

Comment: Note that anything involving constants and $n$ can be factored out of the sum.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Thank you, that's very helpful, I can take it from there!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach you might want to consider:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}5^{3n+k}(-6)^{2k-2} = \dfrac{5^{3n}}{36}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}5^{k}6^{2k} = \dfrac{5^{3n}}{36}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 180^k = \dfrac{5^{3n}}{36}(180+1)^n = \dfrac{5^{3n}}{36}181^n = \dfrac{22625^{n}}{36}$$

Comment: And do you really think that algebra was "simple" for the OP? If not, did the word "simple" add anything to your answer except a nice feeling of superiority for you? (You also didn't answer the OP's question -- how to rewrite $5^{3n+k}$ as $x^{n-k}$ for some $x$, nor explain why that particular thing is impossible as stated.)

Comment: @JohnHughes By this, I meant that the problem can be solved without finding an explicit representation of $5^{3n+k}(−6)^{2k−2}$ in the form $x^{n−k}y^k$, but just using such a "simple algebra". Of course, I didn't mean to sound with a tone of superiority, just wanted to say that the solution is merely a series of elementary algebraic transformations. It might not be simple for the OP, but I believe that he also found it fairly simple. If not, I would be glad to elaborate more on the details.

Comment: @JohnHughes As you may see, in this solution there also appears the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k}y^k = (x+y)^n$ for $x=180, y=1$. The OP asked to write the original expression in such a form that he can use this binomial theorem and turn it into closed form. So I suppose it kind of answers the question of the OP (or at least may be considered as useful).

Comment: @JohnHughes the algebra is pretty much straightforward here, I just hadn't considered this way of solving the problem.

Comment: Your answer would have looked very different if the first two words were replaced by "Here's an alternative approach you might want to consider:"

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, you are probably right. I edited the answer accordingly, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> **Hint:** Another variant to treat $5^{3n+k}$ is to get $n-k$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> n=(n-k)+k
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 5^{3n+k}=5^{3(n-k)+3k+k}=5^{3(n-k)+4k}=\left(5^3\right)^{n-k}\left(5^4\right)^k
> \end{align*}

Since $5^3=125$ and $5^4=625$ we obtain together with
 $(-6)^{2k-2}=\frac{1}{36}\cdot36^k$

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{36}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}125^{n-k}(625\cdot 36)^k=\ldots
> \end{align*}